# Remove records from pandas Dataframe subject to condition

Tags: pandas, contains, drop

I have created the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

ds = {'col1':['a','/','b','c'], 'col2' : [1,2,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
print(df)
```

which looks like this:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    /     2
2    b     3
3    c     4
```

I have a list of special characters `¬`!"£$£#/+*><@|` defined like this:

```
import re

chars = '¬`!"£$£#/\+*><@|'
regex = f'[{"".join(map(re.escape, chars))}]'
```

From the dataframe above, I need to remove only the records for which `col1` contains any of the special characters included in the regex.

From the example above, the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     3
2    c     4
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html?highlight=contains#pandas.Series.str.contains) to get all rows that contain the regex and then negate:

```
df[~df.col1.str.contains(regex)]
```

Result:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     1
2    b     3
3    c     4
```